# Rake task to list all migrations for a given model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rake, rake-task

On the terminal, is there a rake task to list all the migrations which have been run on a particular model? If not, how do I go about building one?

When I ran `rake -T`, `rake db:migrate:status` seemed to be the right answer, but it gave me Migration Name as one of the columns. And though the name `Add logo to company` does indicate Company model, not all migrations have such explicit names. Case in point being `Change data type for content`. I have 400 odd migration files, so this feature would be really helpful.

So, the ideal output would be:

```
database: abcd_development

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name     Model Name
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you've been sticking with the migration naming conventions, you could just pass the output of `rake db:migrate:status` through `grep`:

```
rake db:migrate:status | grep 'compan'
```

This isn't perfect, though - migration names aren't required to have anything to do with what they actually do - a migration might add the column 'name' to the 'companies' table and be named `EvacuateWeaselTubes` and still run just fine.

If you wanted to build a task that could overcome this problem, it would have to parse each of the migration files to see what it changed. Since there's many ways to specify a change in a migration (`add_column`, a `create_table` block, or calling `execute('CREATE whatever')`, for instance), you'd probably want to search for mentions of `Model.table_name`, then check the `schema_migrations` table to see if it had been run.

Comment: Thanks, and though the first method does get work done, I would still love a neat tabular format like I mentioned above. In spite of being a Rails newbie, I'm gonna try to build the rake task you mentioned. I'll keep you posted.